# Magento getProductUrl() is not returning the right url

Tags: magento

I'm stuck in getting the product url in a product collection. I have this pieces of code to get the product collection for setted featured product.

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                  ->getCollection();

 $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('feat_enabled', 1);
 $_productCollection->setVisibility(array(2,3,4));
 $_productCollection->addUrlRewrite();
 $_productCollection->groupByAttribute('entity_id');
 $_productCollection->load();

foreach($_productCollection as $_product){  
       $_product->load($_product->getId());
   if($_product->getIsSalable()){
          $_name = ltrim(rtrim($_product->getName()));
          $_url =  $_product->getProductUrl();
       }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here, if ill echo $_url in each loop, the url being return is lacking. It doesn't have the category name and subcatname. The correct url should be:

> index.php/category/subcategory/itemname.html

But currently it only returns

```
  index.php/itemname.html
```

It returns corrects data except for the url. I have double check in admin if i assigned the item to a category and subcategory , I confirmed that i assigned it.

```
Upon further research, I have found the code below that is very close to what i need.
$_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);
$_url = Mage::getUrl($_category->getUrlPath()).basename($_product->getProductUrl());
```

The problem here, the $_url value became like this

> index.php/category/subcategory.html/itemname.html

The subcategory name has .html in it. I don't need the .html in my url so the item would be redirected to the correct page when clicked.

Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this is that products can appear in multiple categories.

Therefore, at some level, regardless of which way you approach it, you have to involve a category somewhere.

So, the cleanest way of doing this is to use the `addurlRewrite` method and pass the category id.  Magento will check for rewrites matching the category id and product id - if a rewrite is found, you will get the nice urls you are looking for on the `getProductUr`l call.  As an example, using a category id of 10:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addUrlRewrite(10);
```

If you knew that each product would only appear in a single category, then you could make this a little more flexible by using the following to get the first category id:

Therefore a complete example using this method would be:

```
$categoryId = array_shift($_product->getCategoryIds());
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryFilter( $_category )
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1))
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->load();

    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):

        $_product_url = $_product->getProductUrl();

    endforeach;
```

> addUrlRewrite() // does the magic

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behaviour, as the same products can exist in multiple categories.

Comment: Hi, i found a code that is very close to what i need. Please see my question above for details. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great solution.
But it will not works if there are root category included and more depth categories.
I have added some code with your solution:

```
   $cat_count=count($_categories);

   if($cat_count>0){
       if($_categories[0]==2) // here 2 is root category id
       $cat_count=$cat_count-1;
       else
       $cat_count=$cat_count-2;
   }


    $_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[$cat_count]); 

    $caturl=explode('.html', $_category->getUrlPath());      

    $_url = Mage::getUrl($caturl[0]).basename($_product->getProductUrl());
```

Answer (score -1):

For the benefit of those who are having issue same as mine. I have fixed the issue through this way.

```
 foreach($_productCollection as $_product){ 
        $_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);          
        $caturl=explode('.html', $_category->getUrlPath());            
        $_url = Mage::getUrl($caturl[0]).basename($_product->getProductUrl()); 
 }
```

I just explode the .html in the category url path because i want my category url to have .html in it.

I don't know if this is good fixed but this works for me.